# Writing to .txt file from inheritance classes issue (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance

Basically I am trying to save inputs from a data entry (Already been inputted by the user, just trying to print) to a .txt file. This is from a main class, and a child class, but it seems to just be saving the child classes's details...

I simplified the classes/int main in my example as my code is too long.

Any ideas how can I get it to save the 'vehicle' AND 'car' data entries in to the same document together?

Thanks

```
class vehicle {    

public:     

virtual void saveDetails() { 

    ofstream vehiclefile ("vehicle.txt");
    vehiclefile.open ("vehicle.txt");
    vehiclefile << "***Your Vehicle's Details***" << endl;
    vehiclefile << "Manufacturer:" << manufacturer << endl;
    vehiclefile << "Year of Manufacture:" << year << endl;
    vehiclefile << "Registration Number: " << regnum << endl;
    vehiclefile.close();
}


class lorry : public vehicle{

public:

  virtual void saveDetails() { 

    vehicle::saveDetails();

    ofstream vehiclefile;
    vehiclefile.open ("vehicle.txt");
    vehiclefile << "Car or Lorry: Lorry" << endl;
    vehiclefile << "Maximum weight: " << tonnage << endl;
    vehiclefile << "Body type: " << bodtype << endl;
    vehiclefile.close();
}


int main (); {

case '3': 
        v -> saveDetails();
        break;
}
```

Comment: I said in my question :)

It only saves the details from the 'lorry' child class, skipping the details from the parent 'vehicle' class.

Comment: Is it overwriting the file every time? Perhaps you only see the subclass info because each call to ofstream.Open is overwriting the file vehicle.txt? Try using the app (append)  or ate (at end)  open flags

Comment: I've tried it with out the "vehiclefile.open ("vehicle.txt");" in the child class, but it still happens :\

Comment: Try `vehiclefile.open("vehicle. txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app); ` it looks like it's most likely overwriting all data because it starts at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Just a guess but try removing the file name from `ofstream vehiclefile ("vehicle.txt");` in the base class as well as using ios:app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofstream.open takes a mode parameter. It looks like each successive write starts at the front of the file each time you open it. Try setting the mode to app (append)  or ate (at end-though I'm not exactly certain on this behavior because I haven't tested and am posting from my phone)

`vehiclefile.open("vehicle.txt", ios::out | ios::app);` 
It looks like it's most likely overwriting all data because it starts at the beginning of the file and is not appending.

Remove the file name from the constructor in the base class as well, that's causing the file to open and there are no flags specified there... Even if you use them in the call to open you've already opened the file on the previous line.

```
 class vehicle {    

 public:     

 virtual void saveDetails() { 

ofstream vehiclefile;
vehiclefile.open ("vehicle.txt", ios::app|ios::out);
vehiclefile << "***Your Vehicle's Details***" << endl;
vehiclefile << "Manufacturer:" << manufacturer << endl;
vehiclefile << "Year of Manufacture:" << year << endl;
vehiclefile << "Registration Number: " << regnum << endl;
vehiclefile.close();
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/ has some info about the modes.

On the constructor, from link above:

Since the first task that is performed on a file stream is generally to open a file, these three classes include a ***constructor that automatically calls the open member function*** and has the exact same parameters as this member.

Remove the redundant file open and use the append open flag (in both clssses) and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to open the file the second time for append.

Try open with flags like this in your lorry class:

```
vehiclefile.open ("vehicle.txt", ios::out | ios::app );
```

Have a look at:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

EDIT: I added this as a comment, but for clarity I'm adding to this answer too - Oh, additionally your base class is doing a double open. Try either removing the "vehicle.txt" from the constructor OR not calling the open on the next line. Do this in addition to using the aforementioned flags in your child class.

Comment: I've added that in to the lorry class, but it still does not work :\

Comment: @Provoke Then perhaps `v` is not pointing to a `lorry`?  Why don't you add a `std::cerr << "lorry::saveDetails()\n";` line atop that function - see if it's really entering the lorry override...?

Comment: Oh, additionally your base class is doing a double open. Try either removing the "vehicle.txt" from the constructor OR not calling the open on the next line.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through? You didn't specify your IDE, but it should be possible... Otherwise as Tony suggested use cerr or any other means to see that it's actually stepping into the vehicle base class.  If you change the file name in only one of the methods, do you end up with two files? If yes, you aren't properly appending. If no, you don't have a vehicle. Unless the "code you removed"  is doing something else in that base class

Answer (score 0):

@user3495829 is right on the money.  You need to remove the open method from the base class and use the append option when you open in the derived class.  Below is a working example that writes both sets of data to the file.  I've added dummy values so it compiles.

```
#include <fstream>

class vehicle
{
public:
    virtual void saveDetails() 
    { 
        int manufacturer = 5;
        int year = 1989;
        int regnum = 0;

        std::ofstream vehiclefile ("vehicle.txt");
        //vehiclefile.open ("vehicle.txt");  // Remove this
        vehiclefile << "***Your Vehicle's Details***" << std::endl;
        vehiclefile << "Manufacturer:" << manufacturer << std::endl;
        vehiclefile << "Year of Manufacture:" << year << std::endl;
        vehiclefile << "Registration Number: " << regnum << std::endl;
        vehiclefile.close();
    }
};


class lorry : public vehicle
{

public:

    virtual void saveDetails() 
    { 
        int tonnage = 1;
        int bodtype = 1;

        vehicle::saveDetails();

        std::ofstream vehiclefile;
        vehiclefile.open ("vehicle.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app); // Append
        vehiclefile << "Car or Lorry: Lorry" << std::endl;
        vehiclefile << "Maximum weight: " << tonnage << std::endl;
        vehiclefile << "Body type: " << bodtype << std::endl;
        vehiclefile.close();
    }

};

int main ()
{
    vehicle* v = new lorry();

    v -> saveDetails();

    delete v;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! It works now and I understand where I was going wrong.